# How to create multiple directories based on file names and change the file names in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, directory

I have a directory `AllData` with some files like below:

```
AllData
 |____ file_1to1000.track
 |____ file_1001to2000.track
 |____ file_2001to3000.track
```

Based on file names I created directories with file names.

```
for file in *; do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done
```

And I wanted to create another directory inside that and keep the file. It should like below:

```
AllData
 |__ file_1to1000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ file_1to1000.track

 |__ file_1001to2000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ file_1001to2000.track

 |__ file_2001to3000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ file_2001to3000.track
```

After moving the files into directories like above, the file name should be changed from `file_1to1000.track` to `soft.track`. All the files inside directories needs to be changed from their original filename to `soft.track` It should basically look like below:

```
AllData
 |__ file_1to1000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ soft.track

 |__ file_1001to2000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ soft.track

 |__ file_2001to3000
          |___ cuffcompare
                   |____ soft.track
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

```
for file in ./*; do
    echo mkdir -p "${file%.*}"/cuffcompare/ && \
    echo mv "$file" "$_"soft.track
done
```

to liner:

```
for file in ./*; do echo mkdir -p "${file%.*}"/cuffcompare/ && echo mv "$file" "$_"soft.track; done
```

Note: Remove `echo` at above when you were happy with dry-run result.

---

`${file%.*}` strips the shortest matched suffix from the filename. so it cuts `.track` from the end of filename here. known [Parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

`$_` is the substitute of the last argument of the previous command (see [shell Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)); which expands to `"${file%.*}"/cuffcompare/`;

so `mkdir` creates the directories (`-p` is used to create parent directories if those were not exist) structure below for every file found;

```
└── file_2001to3000
    └── cuffcompare
```

then `mv` moves and rename the file to its related directory with `soft.tarck` name:

```
└── file_2001to3000
    └── cuffcompare
        └── soft.track
```